# using a subquery postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do `inner join` between my two tables `turnover` and `contact` where the value of column cat of the turnover table is 'cat1' and total_ belongs to the top 20%.

**Algorithm:**

FILTER ON (cat = cat1 and total_>0) on this list get only those that belongs to the top 20% (total_) yearly. Then do the join with contact_

```
create table turnover (
cod    integer,
cat     varchar(40),
date_      date,
cash       integer,
CB         integer,
total_     integer,
CONSTRAINT turnover_ UNIQUE(cod, cat, date_));

create table contact (
cod    integer,
date_     date,
Type_      varchar(40),
Mail_      integer,
sms         integer, 
phone integer,
total_      integer,
CONSTRAINT cnt UNIQUE(cod, date_, type_)); 

 select t.cod, t.cat, t.date_, t.total_,
   c.cod, c.date_, c.type_, c.total_
  from (select t.*
   from turnover t
   where t.cat = 'cat1' and t.total_ > 0
   ) t Inner join
   contact c
   on t.cod = c.cod
   group by t.date_;
```

Comment: What is the problem? BTW: you do not need the subquery; you could just join the two tables.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve. Please add some sample sample data and desired output along with your algorithm

Comment: I wasn't able to do the 20% @wildplasser. I added my code . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Postgreaql you can use `row_number()` window function and `count()` window function to achieve it. Try below query:

```
select
cod, cat, t_date, total_, c_date, type_, total_
from
(
select 
   t.cod, t.cat, t.date_ "t_date",  t.total_,
   c.date_ "c_date", c.type_, c.total_
   count(*) over (partition by t.date_) as cnt,
   row_number() over (partition by t1.date_ order by t.total_ desc) as rn
from turnover t
inner join contact c on t.cod = c.cod
where t.cat = 'cat1' and t.total_ > 0
) t1
where t1.rn/t1.cnt<=0.20
```

Comment: @alkilesh Mishra thank youu so much . One more question please, as i mentioned i have to do it yearly . Lets notice that my column date_: 2019-01-01, 2018-01-01, 2017-01-01, 2013-01-01, 2012-01-01

Comment: should i simply add group by t.date_ at the end. ? Danke

Comment: yearly means whether you want it for one specific year only?

Comment: i mean every year . @Akhilesh Mishra

Comment: Added the required changes

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is specifically:

```
select t.cod, t.cat, t.date_, t.total_,
       c.cod, c.date_, c.type_, c.total_
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by t.total_ desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from turnover t
      where t.cat = 'cat1' and t.total_ > 0
     ) t join
     contact c 
     on t.cod = c.cod
where t.seqnum <= 0.20 * t.cnt;
```

If you prefer, you can also use `ntile()`:

```
select t.cod, t.cat, t.date_, t.total_,
       c.cod, c.date_, c.type_, c.total_
from (select t.*,
             ntile(5) over (order by t.total_ desc) as tile
      from turnover t
      where t.cat = 'cat1' and t.total_ > 0
     ) t join
     contact c 
     on t.cod = c.cod
where tile = 1;
```

Comment: @biwia . . . A typo.

Comment: do you mean seqnum in place of rn ? @Gordon Linoff